# Multiple bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 divs on 1 page.
Within the divs I have tab containers, but clicking 1 of the tabs within 1 tabcontainer, influence also the tabs of the other container.
Maybe its the css that I am using that cause the problem.
Am I missing something?
Here is my code

```js
$("ul.container-tabs a").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="system">
  <div class="container-tabbed">
    <ul class="container-tabs">
      <li><a href="#system_main" class="active">main</a></li>
      <li><a href="#system_tab_2">tab2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#system_tab_3">tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container-tab active" id="system_main">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
          <div class="page-subtitle">
            system main
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-tab" id="system_tab_2">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
          <div class="page-subtitle">
            tab2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-tab" id="system_tab_3">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
          <div class="page-subtitle">
            tab3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="theme" style="display: none">
  <div class="container-tabbed">
    <ul class="container-tabs">
      <li><a href="#theme_main" class="active"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="container-tab active" id="theme_main">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
       <div class="page-subtitle">
      theme main
       </div>
     </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$("ul.container-tabs a").click(function (e) {
  $($(this).attr('href'))
    .show()
    .siblings('.container-tab')
    .hide();
});
```

```css
.container-tab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="system">
<div class="container-tabbed">
  <ul class="container-tabs">
    <li><a href="#system_main" class="active">main</a></li>
    <li><a href="#system_tab_2">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#system_tab_3">tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="container-tab active" id="system_main">
      <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
        <div class="page-subtitle">
          system main
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-tab" id="system_tab_2">
      <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
        <div class="page-subtitle">
          tab2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-tab" id="system_tab_3">
      <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
        <div class="page-subtitle">
          tab3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="theme" style="display: none">
<div class="container-tabbed">
  <ul class="container-tabs">
    <li><a href="#theme_main" class="active"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="container-tab active" id="theme_main">
      <div class="wrapper wrapper-white">
      <div class="page-subtitle">
      theme main
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Mistake: You forget to hide other tabs (other than the clicked one)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hmm its almost working. 2 Strange things happens. When the page is loaded, then all 3 container-tab's are displayed (system main, tab2 and tab3). You can see it when you run the code snippet above. When setting div with id=system to display=none and div with id=theme to display=block, then all container-tab's are also displayed (in the example above there is only 1 tab: theme_main, but if you add more tabs you will see that behaviour. The tab content is remembered but the selected tab is not selected anymore.

Comment: @Dennis I've solve the first issue **When the page is loaded, then all 3 container-tab's are displayed (system main, tab2 and tab3)**. Can you please help me to understand the second issue with an updated **jsfiddle**?

Comment: That helped 1 piece :)

Comment: @Dennis Can you please update the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wm6wgovL/ with you second issue.

Comment: In the example the selected tab has no other style than the other tabs, but normally you would see which tab is selected

Comment: Ok I updated https://jsfiddle.net/wm6wgovL/4/ Just dont understand why the button are not working

Comment: yes I see, please add the 2 blue buttons like in my https://jsfiddle.net/wm6wgovL/4/

Comment: @Dennis Please have a look into the updated solution https://jsfiddle.net/wm6wgovL/6/

Comment: When clicking the theme button, the tabs disappear of the ' theme div'

Comment: Hmm the behaviour in html page is different then in apsx. see https://jsfiddle.net/wm6wgovL/11/

Comment: In https://jsfiddle.net/wm6wgovL/8/ you can see the tab is not selected, despite the fact that the proper tab content is selected